# Issue with cd in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
cd C:\Windows\System32
set pth=%~dp0
for /f %%D in ('Find /V /C "" ^< "%pth%custom\mscDT.txt"') do (
set custc=%%D
)
cls
set /p dec="Path: "
set path="C:\Users\%username%\%dec%"
set /a i=2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:import
if i==12 goto loopend
if "!path:~-%i%,1!"=="." set ext="!path:~-%i%!"
set /a i=%i%+1
:loopend
echo %ext%
xcopy "%path%" "%pth%custom\cust%custc%%ext%" /y
echo What would you like the file to displayed as?
set /p chose="- "
for /F %%* in (cscript "%pth%GETSZE.vbs" "%path%") do set vars=%%*
echo %vars%
pause
```

Which is meant to copy a file and then run a vbs to get its size and some other stuff later. But when I run it 'cscript' and 'xcopy' are not recognized as commands, even though any other batch file work fine. Does anyone have a fix or reason why this is happening? I have a feeling it has something to do with 'setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion', but I don't have much knowledge of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system can't find XCOPY or CSCRIPT because you're modifying the `PATH` with this statement:

```
set path="C:\Users\%username%\%dec%"
```

If you want to append to your path, try this:

```
set path=%PATH%;C:\Users\%username%\%dec%
```

Or, use a different variable name:

```
set MyPath="C:\Users\%username%\%dec%"
```